# Condition for a full rotation of a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A sphere $(m)$ hangs on one end of a non strechable and weightless thread of length $L$ and the other end is firmly fastened on a pivot $A$.  $(m)$ has initial speed $v_0$ as shown in the picture. Moreover the thread can rotate $360$ degrees with no friction.

If $(m) $ makes a full rotation with respect to $A$ and returns to its original position, with the thread always remaining tight , then when the body reaches the maximum height of its track we have :

$$\sum F=m{v^2\over L}\Longrightarrow T+ mg=m{v^2\over L}\Longrightarrow T=m{v^2\over L}-mg\quad (1)$$

$$ T\geq 0\overset{(1)}{\Longrightarrow} v\geq \sqrt{gL}\quad 2 $$

From the conservation of energy we have:

$${1\over2}mv_0^2={1\over2}mv^2+mg2L\overset{(2)}{\Longrightarrow} v_0\geq \sqrt{5gL}$$

**Question:** Conversely If $v_0\geq \sqrt{5gL}$  $\ $does $(m)$ perform a full rotation with respect to $A$  and does the thread remain tight? If not, is there a condition to do so?

[image]

Comment: I'll suggest you to Take a general angle $\theta$ during the motion of bob  and Find Tension and velocity at any point in terms of general angle $\theta$ and locate the point where Tension is zero(string becomes slacked) and where velocity is zero. Also you can write Tension in terms of velocity to keep track of Tension at different points using velocity at that point.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I can answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $v_0\geq \sqrt{5gL}\quad (1)$

$T-w\cos\theta=m{v^2\over L}\Longrightarrow T=w\cos\theta+m{v^2\over L}\quad (2) $

From the conservation of energy:  $v^2=v_0^2-2gh\quad (3) $

$\cos\theta=\frac{L-h}{L}\quad (4)$

$(2),(3),(4)\Longrightarrow T={m\over L }\Big[gL+v_0^2-3gh \Big] \quad(5)  $

$(1),(5)\Longrightarrow T>0  $  $\ $ so the string doesn't become slacked

$(1),(3)\overset{2L\geq h}{\Longrightarrow} v\geq\sqrt{gL}\Longrightarrow {dS\over dt}\geq \sqrt{gL}\overset{M.V.T.}{\Longrightarrow} \frac{S-S_0}{t-0}\geq \sqrt{gL}\Longrightarrow S\geq t\sqrt{gL}\quad (6)$

$(6) \overset{t\to +\infty}{\Longrightarrow}S\to +\infty$

Therefore $(m)$ performs infinitely many full rotations with respects to $A$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $v_{0}\geq \sqrt{5gL}$ is the necessary and sufficient condition for a body fastened to the end of a non-extensible string of length $L$ to perform vertical circular motion about A without the string being slack at any point of time.